# Let $f(x)$ be continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, and $f'(x)\le 2x$ for every $0<x<1$, prove that $f(x)=x^2$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous in $[0,1]$, differentiable in $(0,1)$, and $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$, and $f'(x)\le 2x$ for every $0<x<1$, prove that $f(x)=x^2$.

Basically I have no idea how to start my proof, I can understand it intuitively but I don't know what kind of proof this is meant to be. 
I would really appreciate a push in the right direction.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: *Hint:* What can you say about the function $g(x) = f(x) - x^2$?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comments, I haven't read that before, I will try to work more on my titles. about the no clue part, I literally had no clue like I started to think about integrals and derivatives but I knew this is not the way so I didn't include it.  I appreciate the hint and I think I get the idea now, if I prove that $g(x)$ is equal to $0$, then I have proved that $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: Do not think about integral. It is false that $f(x)-(0)=\int_0^x f'(t)dt$ unless extra condition is given about $f'$. There exists differentiable function whose derivative is not integrable. You may search "Volterra function".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x)=f(x)-x^{2}$,
then $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$, $g(0)=g(1)=0$,
and $g'(x)\leq0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$. We go to prove that $g(x)=0$
for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Let $x\in(0,1)$. By Mean-Value Theorem, there exists $\xi\in(0,x)$
such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
g(x) & = & g(x)-g(0)\\
 & = & g'(\xi)(x-0)\\
 & \leq & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
By Mean-Value Theorem again, there exists $\eta\in(x,1)$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
-g(x) & = & g(1)-g(x)\\
 & = & g'(\eta)(1-x)\\
 & \leq & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $g(x)=0$ and hence $f(x)=x^{2}$.